# Magit: finding tags after commit

Tags: magit

I often find myself in the following situation:

1. Look at some code in a project (e.g. `string-trim` in `subr-x.el` in Emacs)
2. `magit-blame` to see which commit added that code
3. Wonder which tags of the project comes after that commit

   - Immediate use case is to find a version of Emacs that contains `string-trim`, so as to specify the dependency in a package header

It's not clear how best to achieve step 3. I can get the commit hash from step 2--then what?

Comment: One way to automate it would be to (1) find all tags, (2) `git tag --contains b55aea382c32f4448892265f322a38290ce10305` (that's the commit that added `string-trim` as per your example). You'll get a list of tags. Since Emacs seems to be very consistent in tag names, you can just sort them and choose the earliest one.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the revision buffer (hit enter from the blame buffer),
you should see a line that looks like this:

```
Parent:     41ce6f7027 * lisp/subr.el (string-suffix-p): New function.
Containing: emacs-24 emacs-25 [...] (5 more)
Follows:    mh-e-8.5 (3693)
Precedes:   emacs-24.5-rc3-fixed (2877)
```

The "Follows:" line is generated with `git describe --tags <revision>`,
and the "Precedes:" line is generated with `git describe --contains <revision>`.